# Should the dots used in lambda-calculus notation be typographically treated the way binary relation and binary operation symbols are?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, latex

Within [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453719/where-can-i-learn-about-cartesian-closed-functors-between-categories-of-simply-t) we find the notation $\lambda f . \lambda g . \lambda x.f(g\ x)$, and that causes me to wonder about a point of LaTeX and MathJax usage.

The code `a.b.c.` gets rendered as $a.b.c,$ with the period, or "full stop" if you like, closer to the letter to its left than the one to its right.

As one would expect, the code `a{.}b{.}c` gives more symmetrical results: $a{.}b{.}c$.

But if we put `\newcommand{\.}{\mathbin{.}}` $\newcommand{\.}{\mathbin{.}}$at the begining (or above the `\begin{document}` in $\LaTeX$) then the code `a\.b\.c` gives us $a\.b\.c,$ with an amount of horizontal space appropriate to a binary operation or binary relation symbol (e.g. the code `3+5` will normally result in $3+5$ and not in $3{+}5$).

\begin{align}
& a.b.c \\[5pt]
& a{.}b{.}c \\[5pt]
& a\.b\.c
\end{align}

Which version should be used in this context?

Comment: It's not a binary symbol. Semantically, "punctuation" is probably the closest match among TeX symbol categories, so it's appropriate to format it as just `\lambda x.f`. And anyway, just about everybody does that, so you can consider it the typographical standard.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : How is it done in the _Pacific Journal of Mathematics_?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you check it?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : Via search engines I couldn't quickly find any lambda-calculus notation in PJoM. I mentioned them because they are fastidious about normative rules of typesetting when it comes to details that most people would never notice.

Comment: If this is for submission to a journal, then I would heavily discourage use of the macro name `\.`.  Journals use their own macros, and uncommon single-character macro names like this seem particularly prone to unexpected conflict.  (I agree with being discomfited by treating the `.` as punctuation when, say, the $\mapsto$ in the mathematician's version $f \mapsto g \mapsto x  \mapsto f(g(x))$ is not so treated, but here I agree with @EmilJeřábek's [comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/29045) that one should probably regard this as established convention nonetheless.)

Comment: @LSpice Good point. No need to hypothesize about journals’ own macros: `\.` already *is* a standard LaTeX command (for the text-mode dot-above diacritic), and overloading standard commands in a submission is a bad idea indeed.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5752/should-the-dots-used-in-lambda-calculus-notation-be-typographically-treated-the#comment29161_5752), ah, thanks.  I remembered the spacing macros `\!`, `\,`, `\ `, `\;`, and `\:` (and probably others), but forgot the existing meaning of `\.`.